How to force a match type to be fully reduced on compile?
I don't get why a match type is not always reduced. Match types should help to eliminate illegal arguments on compilation. But as it turns out it does not always reduce in full.
Take this silly example:
sealed trait AB
case class A() extends AB
case class B() extends AB

type OnlyA[X] = X match
    case A => A

def onlyA[X <: Matchable](x: X): OnlyA[X] = x match
    case a: A => a

val isA: OnlyA[A] = onlyA(A())
val isB: OnlyA[B] = onlyA(B()) // fails as expected

val isAorB: OnlyA[AB] = onlyA(B(): AB)          // should fail? does compile, no reduction triggered?
val ev                = summon[OnlyA[AB] =:= A] // show a reduce failure as expected

isB is correctly rejected by the compiler but isAorB should fail because there is no path and it cannot prove it to be disjoint because it could be AB.A.
Strangely when actively using the type in an equality check, it does try to reduce it and fails as expected.
What do I get wrong or is this a compiler bug?

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html#match-type-reduction-1
